# Google Drive SDK Client ID

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I created an application following the Quickstart Android guide for Google Drive sdk. When I setup the project in the api console I was given a client id. But I am not using this client id anywhere. What is the use of the client id? Am I supposed to have it somewhere in my application?

Answer (score 1):

On Android, your **certificate SHA1 fingerprint** and **package name** together is unique identifier of your application. As long as these two matches with information you provided to API console, Drive API will recognize who you are. You don't need to provide your clientId. In case you don't remember providing these two information, you should make special clientID for Android as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android#step_2_enable_the_drive_api).